# Why decrement is not working properly in C programming?

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a pyramid in C, i need to get the next pattern:

```
    A
   ABA
  ABCBA
 ABCDCDA
ABCDEDCBA
```

I need to use nested for loops, but the decrementing is not working properly for me, this is my code:

```
int main(void)

{

    int i, j, k, g;
    char userLatter;
    printf("please enter an uppercase letter:\n");
    scanf("%c", &userLatter);
    int asci = userLatter;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {

        for (j = 4; j > i; j--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        asci = userLatter;
        for (k = 0; k <= i ; k++)
        {
         printf("%c", asci++);
        }


        for (g = 1; g <= i; g++)
        {
            printf("%c", --asci);
        }

        printf("\n"); 
    }

}
```

this is the input "a"

and the output im getting is:

```
    a
   abb
  abccb
 abcddcb
abcdeedcb
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

tnx

Comment: Learn to use your debugger. This will prove a handy skill to have now and in the future.

Comment: How is it not working? You can't just dump some code and expect people to fix it for you. Show your results or the error message you get.

Comment: What decrementing isn't working properly? What do you expect to happen ? What inputs did you give it. What *did* happen?

Comment: When you say "not working", and you don't explain what "not working" means, you might as well save the keystrokes. Explain the problem you're having or the error you're getting, and please remember we can't read your mind or see your screen from here. Expecting us to read through your code trying to figure out what the issue is you're having in order to help you is pretty inconsiderate. You're asking for free help - you could at least put forth the effort to actually explain the problem. :-) Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend using an easy to calculate expression instead of the `asci` variable (such as `'a' + i` or something like that). This way you don't need to worry about order of execution and other increment/decrement issues (those operators are very easy to get wrong!).

Comment: you are right guy's im sorry for omitting important details. i added the input and output @KenWhite

Comment: The edit you added to actually explain the problem is excellent. Thanks! :-) Please remember that for future questions.

Comment: Thank you ken! ouah suggestion fixed my problem :). since im a C beginner, is that a proper solution in C programming? @KenWhite

Comment: As you tried @ouah's solution and it worked, and that solution has received 7 upvotes as of when I'm typing this (including one from me), and the person who answered that question has considerable rep (meaning that their answers are pretty well accepted and trusted here), I'd accept the solution as being correct. :-)

Comment: ohhh no I didnt mean if his solution is consider good, im 1000% sure it is. I meant my overall solution for this task :) @KenWhite

Comment: Your solution is acceptable (as a beginner), although there are other ways to do it. :-) But that's a totally different question that would be appropriate to post on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). StackOverflow is for getting code working in the first place (or using programmers tools), and CodeReview is for asking about improving already working code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a:

```
--asci;
```

between the two `for` loops.

In the first loop, `asci++` performs a *postfix* increment: the expression is evaluated to `asci` and then the object is decremented.

Answer (score 2):

Cosider that

```
printf("%c", --asci);//decreases the value and then prints
```

is different than

```
printf("%c", asci--);//prints and then decreases the value
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight While this may not have given the precise fix, misunderstanding what the line `printf("%c", asci--)` does (or, similarly, `printf("%c", asci++)`) absolutely is it.